# List comprehension for two variable loop in Python and numpy

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have to create a 2D numpy array from the values x, y from a function return to plot using contourf from matplotlib, and so far I'm using a "C" like structure, that it seems to be *very* inefficient in Python:

```
    dim_x = np.linspace(self.min_x, self.max_x, self.step)
    dim_y = np.linspace(self.min_y, self.max_y, self.step)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(dim_x, dim_y)

    len_x = len(dim_x)
    len_y = len(dim_y)


    a = np.zeros([len_x, len_y], dtype=complex)

    for i, y in enumerate(dim_y):
        for j, x in enumerate(dim_x):
            a[i][j] = aux_functions.final_potential(complex(x, y), element_list)

cs = plt.contourf(X, Y, (a.real), 100)
```

How can this be done in a more pythonic way?

Thanks!

Comment: What does your `final_potential` function do?  What you want to do is "vectorize" that function, rather than writing nested loops. `fromfunction` or `vectorize` are fine, but they're just as inefficient as your loop.

Comment: Can you point me to some documentation about "vectorizing" my function?

Comment: Read through the various `numpy` tutorials. (e.g. http://www.tramy.us/numpybook.pdf Also see http://scipy-lectures.github.com/ ) The basic idea is to apply operations to the entire array instead of individual elements.  If you'll give an example of your `final_potential` function, we can help walk you through it.  It's usually quite simple, but it might not be immediately obvious if you haven't done it before.  In some cases (e.g. finite difference methods) it simply can't be done, but these are relatively rare.

Comment: Also, as a quick example, consider a function that takes the `sin` of each item and if the result is greater than 0, multiplies it by 2, otherwise just returning `sin(x)`. This could be written as `result = np.sin(x); result[result > 0] *= 2`, where `x` is an array of your values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be ideal if you could rewrite `final_potential` as a vectorized function. A simple and, perhaps, too-obvious example:

```
>>> dim_x = np.linspace(0, 2, 5)
>>> dim_y = np.linspace(0, 2, 5)
>>> X * Y
array([[ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.25,  0.5 ,  0.75,  1.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.5 ,  1.  ,  1.5 ,  2.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.75,  1.5 ,  2.25,  3.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  1.  ,  2.  ,  3.  ,  4.  ]])
```

But if you *really can't* do that, you could also `vectorize`:

```
>>> np.vectorize(lambda x, y: x * y + 2)(X, Y)
array([[ 2.  ,  2.  ,  2.  ,  2.  ,  2.  ],
       [ 2.  ,  2.25,  2.5 ,  2.75,  3.  ],
       [ 2.  ,  2.5 ,  3.  ,  3.5 ,  4.  ],
       [ 2.  ,  2.75,  3.5 ,  4.25,  5.  ],
       [ 2.  ,  3.  ,  4.  ,  5.  ,  6.  ]])
```

In your case, it would probably look something like this:

```
def wrapper(x, y): 
    return aux_functions.final_potential(complex(x, y), element_list)

a = np.vectorize(wrapper)(X, Y)
```

This will probably be a bit faster than nested `for` loops, although the overhead of a python function call will negate a lot of numpy's efficiency. In tests I've done in the past, using `vectorize` provided a modest 5x speedup. (That's compared to a 100x or 1000x speedup for pure numpy operations, as in the `X * Y` example.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this would increase your performance at all, but there is [numpy.fromfunction](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html) which could be used to construct your array `a`.  Without a nice self-contained example, it will be a little tricky to timeit to see how difference the performance is however.  e.g. how long does it take to run `aux_functions.final_potential`?  If that function is expensive, it doesn't matter how much you optimize the loops around it.

Also, I'd imagine that `a[i,j]` is slightly more efficient than `a[i][j]`, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: +1 for using fromfunction. It wouldn't increase performance, but that wasn't the question